# Is it true that $\int_{\Omega}|\nabla u|^{2}dx = -\int_{\Omega}u\Delta udx$?

Tags: vector-analysis, laplacian

Suppose $\Omega$ be a bounded open set in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. We assume that $u$ is sufficiently smooth so that the calculations make sense. Then is it true that

$$\int_{\Omega}|\nabla u|^{2}dx = -\int_{\Omega}u\Delta udx,$$

or is there something missing?

This is a question that arises from an equation I've seen here
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Integrate by parts on the RHS (which is the same as using the [divergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem#Corollaries), see the fourth dot point and set $c = \nabla u, f = u$). The LHS is usually called the 'Dirichlet energy'.

Comment: yes something is missing: boundary conditions

Answer (score 0):

Recall the divergence theorem
\begin{align}
\iiint_R \operatorname{div}(\mathbf{F})\ dV = \iint_{\partial R} \mathbf{F}\cdot\mathbf{n}\ dS.
\end{align}
Let $\mathbf{F}= u\nabla u$, then we see
\begin{align}
\iiint_U \{|\nabla u|^2+u\Delta u\}\ dV=\iiint_U \operatorname{div}(u\nabla u)\ dV = \iint_{\partial U} u\frac{\partial u}{\partial \mathbf{n}} dS = 0
\end{align}
since $u\equiv 0$ on the boundary.

Comment: Strictly speaking, must there be $n$ integrals, right? besides $dU$ instead of $dV$.